# How to refresh page with Ajax and MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**I have the code of MVC Application.**

```
<div id="principal">
<table class="table-long">

    <tr>
         <th>
            <a href="" rel="IdSolicitacao" class="orderByLink">
                Número
            </a>
        </th>
         <th>
            <a href="" rel="DataSolicitacao" class="orderByLink">
               Data da Solicitação 
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="" rel="DataColeta" class="orderByLink">
                Data da Coleta
            </a>
        </th>
         <th>
            <a href="" rel="NomeDocumento" class="orderByLink">
                Nome do Documento
            </a>
      </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
    @{
    if (ViewBag.Routes.ContainsKey("id"))
    {
        ViewBag.Routes.Remove("id");
    }
    ViewBag.Routes.Add("id", item.IdSolicitacao);
    }

    <td>
        <input value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdSolicitacao)" class="Solicitacao" style="width:60px;"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.DataSolicitacao.ToShortDateString()
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.DataColeta.ToShortDateString()
    </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeDocumento)
    </td>

</table>
```

i need to refresh this but not reload all page.
how to make refresh of div with id= "principal" without reload all page?
What do u need? create a new view with params?

Comment: You could create a partial view, render it initially in this page, then render each time you want an update (using something like `$('#principal').load('partialwhatever/params');` in JQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
$( "#principal" ).load( document.URL + " #principal" );
```

Comment: That's right, but when i execute this all configuration of css is empty. why?

Comment: Could you explain in more details?

Comment: When i execute load with setInterval for refresh
has this css:

 $(".Prioridade").each(function (index, element) {
            if ($(element).val() == "Urgente") {
                $(element).css({ "background-color": "red",
                    "border": "none", "color": "white", "text-align": "center", "font-size": "0.9em"
                });
                $(element).parent().css("background-color", "red");

and it's not execute

Comment: your styles were set by javascript?

Comment: And Other Information, if i have any filter it's modify and change to empty filter, not keeps

Comment: you should re-apply your styles after load

Comment: In this case i think we have to use the ajax, because have filters and when the div is reload filters lost. how can i make this?

Comment: Hey Andrei, that's Ok. Thanks for help